# Creating a Pandas Panel with Non-Unique Index Objects

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data file `LawSchoolSample.csv`:

```
LSAT,GPA
622,3.23
542,2.83
579,3.24
653,3.12
606,3.09
```

I'd like to create a pandas dataframe, and then resample from this dataframe `B` times to form a pandas panel.  Here's my attempt (critiques welcomed):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("LawSchoolSample.csv")

B = 3
resamples = {}

for i in range(0,B):
    name = "Resample {}".format(i)
    resamples[name] = df.sample(5,replace=True)

print resamples

resamples_panel = pd.Panel(resamples)
```

All is well except the last line: `resamples_panel = pd.Panel(resamples)`.  The error is:

```
pandas.core.index.InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

I have two questions, then:

1. Is using a `panel` worth it for this?  Or is whatever data structure `resamples` is good enough?
2. What's the preferred method of adding `dataframes` to a panel?

Comment: Regarding 2, there seems to be a suitable method: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_panel.html

Answer (score 0):

The long term plan is to deprecate `Panel`, see pandas documentation:

> In a future version of pandas, we will be deprecating Panel and other
>   >2 ndim objects. In order to provide for continuity, all NDFrame objects have gained the .to_xarray() method in order to convert to
>   xarray objects, which has a pandas-like interface for > 2 ndim.
>   (GH11972)

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.0/whatsnew.html#to-xarray